# MySQL Update statement doesn't work Image Gallery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image, gallery

I have a table named images_users, into this table I have

---

1 img_uploader,
2 img_name,
3 img_id,
 4 img_type,
5 img_size,
6 img_upload_date,
7 img_description
8 img_new_name
 9 img_modification

---

While in upload phase I insert informations into 1/2/3/4/5/6 
so now in the modification page I cannot at all Change any Value I tried doing this, But nothing at all changes

---

```
$req = $BDD->prepare('UPDATE images_users SET 
                                                    img_name =:NEW_img_name, 
                                                    img_id   =:NEW_img_id,, 
                                                    img_new_name =:NEW_img_new_name,
                                                    img_description =:NEW_img_description,
                                                    img_modification = NOW()
                                                    WHERE img_uploader =:username

                                ');
            $req->execute(array(        
                                        'NEW_img_name'         =>   $nom_image_old, 
                                        'NEW_img_id'           =>   $shuffled,
                                        'NEW_img_new_name'     =>   $nom_image_new,
                                        'NEW_img_description'  =>   '',
                                        'username'             =>   $_SESSION['username'],

                                ));
```

SO where is the problem **:D** ????

Comment: You need to add `:` in front of each array key you pass to `execute()`.

Comment: @TomasCreemers, `:` is not required when you are passing array, it'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra comma in your update statement at `img_id   =:NEW_img_id,,`

Try:

```
$req = $BDD->prepare('UPDATE images_users SET 
                                                img_name =:NEW_img_name, 
                                                img_id   =:NEW_img_id,  
                                                img_new_name =:NEW_img_new_name,
                                                img_description =:NEW_img_description,
                                                img_modification = NOW()
                                                WHERE img_uploader =:username

                            ');
```